# "Stresiĝi" kontraŭ "Ek-stresi"

Tags: affixes

Ni scias, ke la afikxoj *-iĝ* kaj *ek-* havas diferencajn signifojn. Tamen, laŭ PIV, *ekstresi* kaj *stresiĝi* estas prefekte samaj signife:

> **stresiĝi:** Ekesti en stato de streso.

([ligilo](http://vortaro.net/#stresi))

Ĉu tio ĝustas? Se jes, kial?

Answer (score 6):

`-iĝ'` kun la signifo *fariĝi* (ĉi tie limigita aplikeble), implicas disvolvon/transiron de unu stato al al alia. Tio do estas daŭro, fluo.

`ek-` kun la signifo de *komenco*, estas pli abrupta.

Do eĉ se la signifoj estas samaj, la nuancasocioj diferencas:

- Mi stresiĝis pro la daŭraj telefonvokoj.
- Mi ekstresis pro la lastminute donita laboro.

Do eble post la unuaj du telefonvokoj mi jam estis duonstresita.

Comment: Mi dubas pri viaj ekzemploj. Vidu : https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/what-is-stress-in-esperanto

Comment: Laŭ _PIV_, la ekzemploj ĝustas.

Comment: Klare. Mi volis diri ke PIV eraras.

Answer (score 3):

Efektive, mi ne vidas la vorton "ekstresi" en PIV. Ja veras ke la vortero "ek" troviĝas en la difino de "stresiĝi", sed oni ne tro valorigu tiun detalon.

Al la pli ĝenerala demando (**ĉu "ek" egalas "iĝ"**) - la respondo estas "nur ĉe kelkaj radikoj" - ekzemple *stari* kaj *sidi*.

Pli grava demando estas ĉu vere necesas por via celo uzi la radikon "stres-"

Vidu

[What is "stress" in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/what-is-stress-in-esperanto/1718#1718)

Comment: Dankon por via bona respondo. Tiu radiko, tamen, perfekte ekspresas la celita signifo, kiel _PIV_ kaj la vortaro de _Lernu_ implicas. _Streĉa_ in viajn ekzemplojn in tiu retpaĝo tradukigas en Angla  al _tense_ aŭ similaj vortoj, ne _stress(ful)_. _Stres-_ signifas _stress_ en biologio kaj psikologio. (Vidu ankaŭ [_Streso_](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streso) in Vikipedio.)

Comment: Legu la respondojn al la alia demando por vidi la bonajn kialojn por konkludi ke PIV eraras pri "streso".

Answer (score 2):

Ĉe verboj, kies baza signifo estas stata (ili esprimas ion nek dinamikan nek  ŝanĝiĝantan, ekz. *vivi, kuŝi, esti*), la signifoj de *-iĝ-* kaj *ek-* estas tiel similaj, ke oni povas uzi ilin preskaŭ internŝanĝe: *sidiĝi - eksidi*.

La diferenco konsistas en tio, ke *ek-* montras nur la komencon de io, do *ekstresi* montras, ke estas stato, kaj ke ĝi havas komencon (simbole: |---); dum *-iĝ-* montras la transiron al alia stato, do *streŝigi* estas stato, kiu estas estiĝanta (simbole: ...---).
Dum verboj kun *ek-* do estas stataj, tiuj kun *-iĝ-* povas ankaŭ esprimi la daŭron de la transiro. Tial ĉi-lastajn oni povas uzi ankaŭ en dinamikaj esprimoj:

- Ĝi eksidis sur la fotelo.
- Ĝi sidiĝis sur la fotelo.
- Ĝi sidiĝis malrapide sur la fotelon, kiam iu ĝin forprenis kaj ĝi falis sur la postaĵon
- *Ĝi eksidis malrapide sur la fotelon, kiam iu ĝin forprenis kaj ĝi falis sur la postaĵon.

Comment: Ja povas esti ke vi pravas pri "verboj, kies baza signifo estas stata", sed mi ŝatus vidi pli da informoj pri tio. Mi estas konvinkebla, sed ankoraŭ ne konvikita, ke vi pravas. Ĉu vere "viviĝi" (tre malofta vorto) egalas al "ekvivi" (eĉ pli malofta vorto.)? PMEG indikas ke "mortiĝi" ne egalas al "(ek)morti." Mi ĝenerale komprenas ke "eksidi = sidiĝi" estas kvazaŭ-idiotismo en Esperanto kaj ne priskribas ĝeneralan regulon.

Comment: La okazo de _morti_ ne estas komparebla, ĉar la radiko esprimas statŝanĝon - _ek-_ kun ĝi ne havas grandan utilon (komenci morti?), kaj _-iĝ-_ kun tiaj verboj aldonas (arkaikan) nuancon de akcidento, kontraŭvoleco.
PMEG priskribas la uzon ĉi tie: http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/igh.html#i-d6f , sed bedaŭrinde uzas iom konfuzan terminaron. Ĝiaj "agaj radikoj" estu "verbaj radikoj" (de kiuj agaj radikoj estas subklaso, kiu nin ĉi tie ne koncernas).